# Transform(redirect) URL segment to a GET parameter

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I know this has probably been answered but I can't find anything specific to my issue.

I have URLS like this:

```
https://staging.books.co.za/travelguide/route-map/SAFI546754
https://staging.books.co.za/travelguide/route-map/SAFI189444
https://staging.books.co.za/travelguide/route-map/SAFI978634
```

and I need them to be redirected to URLS like this:

```
https://staging.books.co.za/travelguide/route-map?reference=SAFI546754
https://staging.books.co.za/travelguide/route-map?reference=SAFI189444
https://staging.books.co.za/travelguide/route-map?reference=SAFI978634
```

Please help...What would the rule look like in my .htaccess file???

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^travelguide/route-map/(.+) /travelguide/route-map?reference=$1
```

See here for a demo http://htaccess.mwl.be?share=6c2be57a-6bb7-5083-9122-aaf63162b240

Comment: Tried this one too and still no luck. Maybe a rewrite condition as well? Sorry about that, should have said so in the question

Comment: You're absolutely right, without a `RewriteCond` it ends up looping I think. I have edited my answer accordingly to only run the rule if the URL doesn't contain a query string already.

Comment: Good answer. I missed out the `/route-map/` part which is what broke mine. This should be the accepted answer, works well when I test it also. +1

Answer (score 0):

Try and use this in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^travelguide/route-map/([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/?$ route-map?reference=$1 [L]
```

Make sure you clear your cache before testing this.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried that and no luck. I think I also need the rewrite condition? Sorry for not including that in the question