# Firebase database prevent spam requests on path reads without authentications?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have many paths in my firebase database enable for read without authentication. How do I prevent spammers? What if someone writes a program and repeatedly sending requests to read all the paths in my db? Is there a way to prevent a limit number of repeated requests from a particular IP?

Comment: There is no filter by IP in security rules. But there's definitely things you can do in your security rules to make abuse harder. The exact approach would depend on the specific abuse you're trying to prevent. So: think of something an attacker might do, write (and if you want help: *share*) the minimal code they could use to do that, then write security rules that make the abusive code fail while keeping your actual app code working. If there is no way to distinguish between your app code and the malicious code, it'll be pretty hard to secure.

Comment: I think that @FrankvanPuffelen covered it with his comment. My additional comment is if an app is created that has data that can be read with no authentication then why try to prevent that data from being read with no authentication? i.e. it's counter intuitive to open up that data to anybody and then try to limit access. Wouldn't it be more secure to require authentication to read the data in the first place? Perhaps you can provide a specific use case as to why you have data available in the open and we can suggest a alternative design to secure that data?

Comment: @Jay I'm using firebase db for Website, not for the mobile app. I want to prevent users from repeatedly sending requests. In normal use, a legitimate user will not send more than 100 in a day (normal would be 10 or 20) to my website. Some data scraping guys, send thousands of request to get data from my site. So, I want to prevent repeated requests if it goes beyond 100 per IP.

Comment: You're not going to be able to do that directly. You are essentially asking how to prevent a user from sending requests to *Firebase* and there isn't such an animal. Does it matter anyway? If your Firebase can be read without authentication, anyone can read the data and bypass your website. i.e. if I knew your firebase url, I could write an app that would send thousands of requests and read that data independently of your site. The answer, as I mentioned, is to use authentication and incorporate rules which will prevent the read requests from completing.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what is your situation, only that is a website, but if you want to make a ip filter you can make a method.

If you can pass the information from php file, you can delimit the access using a .htaccess for redirect url with parameters to a php file, where can access to firebase with authentication, with a verification first the ip adress, using another table.

This method is an implementation, but can semplify your problem using only one php file. This is an method [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45759558/transformredirect-url-segment-to-a-get-parameter), but is only if you want to mask the data.

If you make this, you need to rewrite all you url from firebase to that php, as i said before i don't know the situation.

I hope i have helped you.